# Не становится видимым FrameLayout Android

Tags: java, android

Всем привет.
У меня имеется editText ввод в который выводит результата запроса в RecyclerView.
Я хочу по центру вывести "Ничего не найдено" в двух случаях.

1. Перед началом ввода в EditText(ведь у нас adapter пустой)
2. Если в Adapter добавляются List размером 0 (нету результата).

Для этого я создал layot **list_empty_view**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/list_empty_view">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/result_empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Который как раз отвечает за ничего не найдено

Затем я внедрил его в основной View фрагмента

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etv_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/refresher">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <include
                layout="@layout/error_view"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
            <include
                layout="@layout/list_empty_view"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

И поставил ему visible (так как перед началом ввода - результат равен 0), а другим gone

Затем имеются 2 метода, которые отвечают за результат запроса по API и добавление в adapter

```
private void showError() {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        mErrorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mListEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    private void showData(List<Result> mResultList) {
        if(mResultList.size() == 0){
            mListEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            mListEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        mResultAdapter.addData(mResultList, true);
        mErrorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
```

Но у меня ничего не найдено, ни разу не показалась, ни в начале, ни при получения результата 0.
Подозреваю, что что-то в разметке неправильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` должен содержать только одного потомка. Вынесите ваши остальные вьюхи из него и поместите на один уровень с `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Поместите их после него во `FrameLayot` чтобы они отображались поверх последнего.

Comment: спасибо. Я в SwipeRefreshLayout добавил FrameLayout, куда уже засунул все остальные элементы

Comment: @danilshik, ну... Если работает - то круто) Но мне кажется более правильным оставить `RecyclerView` единственным элементом внутри `SwipeRefreshLayout`